# Batch Size From Keras Output Is Different From My Training Set

Tags: tensorflow, batchsize

I have a question on the batch size number showing up in keras output.
I've gone through similar posts on how to interpret keras outputs and figured out that the number `219` shown in the `result` is the number of batch_size. However, you can see that my X_train batch_size is 7000, not 219. Where did this 219 come from?

```
X_train.shape # (7000, 50, 1)
Y_train.shape # (7000, 50, 10)


model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 1]),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(10))
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01))
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10)
```

Partial result:

```
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01))...
Epoch 1/10
219/219 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 6.0260e-06
Epoch 2/10
219/219 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 1.1669e-08
Epoch 3/10
219/219 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 7.6153e-08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in model.fit the default batch size is 32. So if you have 7000 samples then the steps per epoch is 7000/32=218.75 which gets rounded up to 219. So what this means is to go through your 7000 samples it fetches 32 images for each batch and does that 219 times.